# Getting kafka metrics using go sarama library

Tags: go, apache-kafka, metrics, sarama

I've been trying to get kafka broker metrics using go sarama library and I have few concerns.

I initialized a sarama config using sarama.NewConfig() with the version as sarama.V2_0_0_0 and I used this config to obtain metrics as mentioned in their [doc](https://godoc.org/github.com/Shopify/sarama)

```
`metrics.GetOrRegisterMeter("incoming-byte-rate", config.MetricRegistry).RateMean()`
```

1. Does this provide the total incoming byte rate including all the incoming messages? Because I compared this value with lenses and other tools but it is totally different (same for "outgoing-byte-rate" and "request-rate". I suppose this request rate implies the message rate).
2. Unlike `RateMean()` function, `Rate1()`, `Rate5()` and `Rate15()` return only 0 though there's plenty of activity in the kafka cluster. Do you know any reason for this?
3. I used `metrics.GetOrRegisterMeter(fmt.Sprintf("incoming-byte-rate-for-broker-%v", broker.ID()), config.MetricRegistry).RateMean()` to get broker level metrics as mentioned in the 
   [doc](https://godoc.org/github.com/Shopify/sarama) but I only received 0.

I'd really appreciate if someone can help me out here and enlighten me on these concerns. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Nope. Instead I used a workaround for all metrics requirements by spawning up a prometheus instance internally within the go execution and fetching metrics via JMX exporter in kafka cluster.